# Why ASG Tagging in Terraform uses list of maps instead of a single map?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, tagging

### #1. AWS Resource Tagging Using Terraform (single map)

```
resource "aws_vpc" "example" {
  # ... other configuration ...

  tags = {
    Name = "MyVPC"
  }
}
```

### #2. ASG Tagging (list of maps)

```
resource "aws_autoscaling_group" "asg_ec2" {
    ..........
    ..........

    lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
    }

  tag {
    key                 = "Name"
    value               = "awesome-app-server"
    propagate_at_launch = true
  }

  tag {
    key                 = "Role"
    value               = "server"
    propagate_at_launch = true
  }

  dynamic "tag" {
    for_each = var.tags

    content {
      key    =  tag.key
      value   =  tag.value
      propagate_at_launch =  true
    }
  }

}
```

### Question:

Normally all resources are tagged using a map as shown in #1  above

But all blogs and documentation always suggest tagging for ASG using a "list of maps" and not just a map as shown in #2 above.

Would like to understand why this deviation only for ASG?

Comment: "documentation always suggest tagging for ASG using a "list of maps"" - which documentation? TF docs state that list of maps is **deprecated**, so its unclear where did you find that it is suggested to use always list of maps?

Comment: The Hashicorp Terraform documentation for ASG shows example for tagging using list of maps - https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/autoscaling_group

Comment: Could you please share he document that says list of maps is deprecated? that'd really help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[TF docs](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/autoscaling_group) states that `tags` is depricated:

> tags (Optional, **Deprecated use tag instead**) Set of maps containing resource tags. Conflicts with tag. See Tags below for more details.

So you shoudn't be using `tags` as it is going to be removed in future.

Comment: Wow! I did not see that coming! Thank you for pointing it out - it appears i overlooked this in the documentation!